# How to ideally store images on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, gzip, compression, images

I want to store a huge number of images on Amazon S3 (served via Cloudfront). Currently the way I am doing is simply dumping the images and having basic HTTP Cache headers set to a month so that users can have fast browsing experience. But I still want more fast experience.

Is there anyway I can compress my images (like gzip for text) and users can access that image resource on their browsers.

Comment: Unless you're uploading RAW/BMP files, image files are already extensively compressed. Are you resizing them to the size they'll appear on the web, at least?

Comment: Yes I am having resized JPEGs.

Comment: @EEAA dude, I wrote I am serving via cloudfront (its a CDN only)

Comment: whoops, missed that. :)

Comment: @EEAA no problem. Any suggestion with regard to compression which browser can recognize like gzip for text.

Comment: @SushantGupta JPEGs are already compressed. Unless you want to re-encode them with a lower quality setting (which'll make them look significantly worse, usually) they're already as good as they're getting.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for the advice. Had it been posted as an answer I would have accepted it. But since you haven't, A BIG thanks :)

Comment: @SushantGupta I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPEGs are already inherently a compressed format, so further compression isn't really something that'll give you any significant benefit. You could reencode them with a lower quality setting but that'll compromise their appearance significantly.